# rails 6 active storage add custom column

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6, rails-activestorage

In Rails 6 I have a model named post:

```
# post.rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :uploads
end
```

This model uses active storage. Is there a possibility to add a custom column (e.g. active: boolean) to the active storage 'uploads'?
I would like to avoid the detour via an 'upload' model.
My goal would be that e.g. this query is possible:

```
post.uploads.first.active
```

Thanks,
Andreas

Comment: Try the solution shared in rails github issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/42057